# NotesXSPDocument with Agent runWithDocumentContext

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs, lotus-notes

when i try to pass an NotesXSPDocument to an agent with runWithDocumentContext to manipulate some fields, i never get the new values to the frontend fields. I have tried a fullrefresh and a partialrefresh. When i just print the field value i get the changes successfully.

Here is an example of the XPage

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">

    <xp:panel id="thePanel">
        <xp:this.data>
            <xp:dominoDocument var="document" formName="from"></xp:dominoDocument>
        </xp:this.data>
        <xp:button value="Label" id="button1">
            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                refreshMode="partial" refreshId="thePanel">
                <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:
var agent = database.getAgent("test");
agent.runWithDocumentContext( document.getDocument());
print( "Value-->" +  document.getDocument().getItemValueString("InMemReturn"));}]]>
                </xp:this.action>
            </xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:button>

        <xp:br></xp:br>
        <xp:br></xp:br>
        <xp:inputText id="inputText1" value="#{document.InMemReturn}"></xp:inputText>
    </xp:panel>

</xp:view>
```

here is the Agent

```
Option Public
Option Declare


Sub Initialize

 Dim session As New NotesSession
 Dim doc As NotesDocument

 Set doc = session.Documentcontext
 doc.Appenditemvalue "InMemReturn", CStr(Now)

End Sub
```

Have I missed something?

Comment: Yes. The input field overwrites the return value. Change it to a computed field and try again

Comment: But i need the inputfield. After the agent run i maybe have to change the values in the document

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manipulating documents in agents that bound to input fields are tricky. The XPages runtime isn't really aware what the agent is doing. Quite often you are actually better off converting an agent into a Java bean and call that one. It gives you the opportunity to clean up code and optimize performance. It also removes the performance penalty of loading the agent runtime for an operation.
"I want to reuse existing code" is often overrated here...

But you asked... so here we go. The documentation suggest you can use

```
agent.runWithDocumentContext(document.getDocument(true));
```

to ensure backend changes are applied. Try that and let us know how it went. I actually would take a slightly different approach and bind the input field to a view variable and write that one only back on the save event. Something like:

```
 <xp:inputText id="inputText1" value="#{viewScope.InMemReturn}"></xp:inputText>
```

and in your SSJS:

```
     var agent = database.getAgent("test");
     var doc = document.getDocument(true);
     agent.runWithDocumentContext(doc);
     viewScope.InMemReturn = doc.getItemValueString("InMemReturn");
```

and in a querySave event:

```
     document.getDocument().replaceItemValue("InMemReturn",viewScope.InMemReturn);
```

Let us know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks. I know that it is not a good solution to use an agent. But i have to try to convert a lot of existing business logic (lotusscript) to an xpages application. Your solution works, but my agent manipulates sometimes more thant 80 fields and the fields are not always the same. If this is the only solution that works, i would prefer to translate to code to java. I would love to see a function like notesxspdocument.syncWithNotesDocument(notesdocument) or something like this :)

Comment: I feel your pain. For multiple fields you could use a helper bean. The bean implements the Map interface. It loads the values from the Doc and you bind to it. Before calling the agent you write the value into the doc and after calling back into the bean. Using an internal map this is generic. Use the bean as object data source. And feel free to accept the answer

Comment: Sounds like a plan. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score -1):

You dont save the document in the Agent

```
     Call Doc.save(false,true,false)
```

Comment: With runWithDocumentContext you don't have to save the document. But i tried it with save and it also does not work